# Rails returning 401 on valid devise log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm following [this](https://medium.com/@avatsaev/angular-2-and-ruby-on-rails-user-authentication-fde230ddaed8) guide. And I'm on the step where I try to use HTTPie to get a 200 success response from the server.

```
http -a peter@cleanpixel.nl POST http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in

http: password for peter@cleanpixel.nl@localhost:3000:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
X-Request-Id: 173aea74-eef6-4070-b3bb-832f39a2a7ba
X-Runtime: 0.055728

{
    "errors": [
        "Invalid login credentials. Please try again."
    ]
}
```

But I've checked, double checked and triple checked the details. They are correct.

This is my user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable,
         :trackable,
         :validatable,
         :confirmable,
         :omniauthable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

This is the seed:

```
User.create({email: 'peter@cleanpixel.nl', password: "********", password_confirmation: "*********"})
```

The application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  include Response
end
```

Is my HTTPie call wrong? Did I forget to config something in Ruby or with Devise somewhere? I've seen people having troubles with 401 and Devise, but it looked like the solutions were for older versions.

I've tried a few curl commands now, but no success.

`curl -v -X "POST" "http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -d $'{"email": "user@example.com","password": "monkey67"}'`  returns:

> curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 9

If I run `curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in -d '{"email":"user@example.com", "password":"monkey67"}'` I get:

> Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
>   * Could not resolve host: application
>   * Closing connection 0
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
>   Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
>   * Could not resolve host: application
>   * Closing connection 1
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
>   Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
>   *   Trying ::1...
>   * TCP_NODELAY set
>   * connect to ::1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
>   *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
>   * TCP_NODELAY set
>   * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#2)
>   POST /auth/sign_in HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost:3000
>   User-Agent: curl/7.54.1
>   Accept: */*
>   Content-Length: 25
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> - upload completely sent off: 25 out of 25 bytes
>     < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>     < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>     < Vary: Origin
>     < Cache-Control: no-cache
>     < X-Request-Id: e10c2484-30c9-49e0-b5c2-3404ba311ac7
>     < X-Runtime: 0.065560
>     < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>     <
>     {"errors":["Invalid login credentials. Please try again."]}* Connection #2 to host localhost left intact
>     curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 18

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in your request, you're only passing the email, you need to add the password too. If you're using HHTPie, as you said, you need to give the password as described in the [HTTPie documentation](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie#10authentication).

You must use something like

```
http -a peter@cleanpixel.nl:some_password POST  http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in
```

Comment: It does ask for the password when I use the request as stated. I'll give it a try. `Pass a username:password pair as the argument. Or, if you only specify a username (-a username), you'll be prompted for the password before the request is sent.`

Comment: What happens if you try to login using crul as the article mention at the end?

curl -v -X "POST" "http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     -d $'{
  "email": "peter@cleanpixel.nl",
  "password": "some_password"
}'

Comment: When I try to run the command I get the error: `Started POST "/auth/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-03 21:27:10 +0200
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

$'{email:
  
ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (822: unexpected token at '$'{email:'):`

Comment: Just remove the ```$```.

Comment: Yea, I've tried that. Good news is that I get a 200 response when I check the login through the browser, so that's good.

Comment: So, the probem is at your request. You can try a different tool to connect?

Comment: Yea I've tried a few tools, but none of them give back a good response so I skipped that part of the guide.